# Android: Background images for relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout

What is the size of the background images (png files)? How do I determine the size of the image? (I would like to cover the entire relative layout, thus the entire screen)

Do I need to have several png files, all with the same image but with different sizes to be supported on all screens? (3.7 inch, 4.2 inch, tablet size and etc...)
Can anyone help?
I though of having 1 image and then streching it according to the screen size retrievd from the device system, is this the correct method?

Answer (score 1):

you can use fill parent but for accurate info
use http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch

it will help you to provide resources it is the developers site -- it has info on providing resourses you can also see supporting multiple screens for better understanding